# Qml button list not displayed when using Repeater

Tags: c++, qt, qml

The post is extremely long, as it contains much code, but i feel like my problem is trivial.

I have just started to learn Qt Qml, by following Nicholas Sheriffs' book: *Build modern, responsive cross-platform desktop applications with Qt, C++, and QML* from which the whole idea come.

Following authors' idea, I'm trying to implement context sensitive buttons that would be displayed in different views.

In order to do that, I have implemented Command class that represents single button:

```
#ifndef COMMAND_H
#define COMMAND_H

#include <functional>

#include <QObject>
#include <QScopedPointer>
#include <QString>

#include <cms-lib_global.h>

namespace cms {
namespace framework {

class CMSLIBSHARED_EXPORT Command : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString ui_iconCharacter READ iconCharacter CONSTANT)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString ui_description READ description CONSTANT)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool ui_canExecute READ canExecute NOTIFY canExecuteChanged)

public:
    explicit Command(QObject* parent = nullptr,
                     const QString& iconCharacter = "",
                     const QString& description = "",
                     std::function<bool()> canExecute = [](){ return true; });
    ~Command();

    const QString& iconCharacter() const;
    const QString& description() const;
    bool canExecute() const;

signals:
    void canExecuteChanged();
    void executed();

private:
    class Implementation;
    QScopedPointer<Implementation> implementation;
};

}
}


#endif // COMMAND_H



//command.cpp

#include "command.h"

namespace cms {
namespace framework {

class Command::Implementation{
public:
    QString iconCharacter;
    QString description;
    std::function<bool()> canExecute;

    Implementation(const QString& _iconCharacter,
                   const QString& _description,
                   std::function<bool()> _canExecute)
        : iconCharacter(_iconCharacter),
          description(_description),
          canExecute(_canExecute) {}

};

Command::Command(QObject* parent, const QString& iconCharacter,
                 const QString& description, std::function<bool()> canExecute)
    : QObject(parent){
    implementation.reset(new Implementation(iconCharacter, description, canExecute));
}

Command::~Command()
{
}

const QString& Command::iconCharacter() const
{
    return implementation->iconCharacter;
}

const QString& Command::description() const
{
    return implementation->description;
}

bool Command::canExecute() const
{
    return implementation->canExecute();
}

}
}
```

Command Class is handled within CommandController class:

```
#ifndef COMMANDCONTROLLER_H
#define COMMANDCONTROLLER_H


#include <QObject>
#include <QtQml/QQmlListProperty>

#include <cms-lib_global.h>
#include <framework/command.h>


namespace cms {
namespace controllers {

class CMSLIBSHARED_EXPORT CommandController : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<cms::framework::Command>
               ui_createPatientViewContextCommands READ
               ui_createPatientViewContextCommands CONSTANT)
public:
    explicit CommandController(QObject* _parent = nullptr);
    ~CommandController();

    QQmlListProperty<cms::framework::Command> ui_createPatientViewContextCommands();
public slots:
    void onCreateClientSaveExecuted();

private:
    class Implementation;
    QScopedPointer<Implementation> implementation;
};

}
}

#endif // COMMANDCONTROLLER_H

//commandcontroller.cpp

#include "commandcontroller.h"

#include <QList>
#include <QDebug>

using namespace cms::framework;

namespace cms{
namespace controllers{

class CommandController::Implementation{

public:
    //Controller
    CommandController* commandController {nullptr};
    //Commands
    QList<Command*> createClientViewContextCommands{};


    Implementation(CommandController* _commandController) :
        commandController(_commandController)
    {

        Command* createClientSaveCommand = new Command(commandController,
                                                       QChar( 0xf0c7 ),
                                                       "Save");

        QObject::connect(createClientSaveCommand,
                         &Command::executed,
                         commandController,
                         &CommandController::onCreateClientSaveExecuted);

        createClientViewContextCommands.append(createClientSaveCommand);

    }


};

CommandController::CommandController(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent){
    implementation.reset(new Implementation(this));
}

CommandController::~CommandController(){

}

QQmlListProperty<Command> CommandController::ui_createPatientViewContextCommands(){
    return QQmlListProperty<Command>(this, implementation->createClientViewContextCommands);
}

void CommandController::onCreateClientSaveExecuted(){
    qDebug() << "You executed the Save command!";
}


}
}
```

With that in place, i registered both created types within Qml  inside main.cpp :

```
 qmlRegisterType<cms::framework::Command>("CMS", 1, 0, "Command");
 qmlRegisterType<cms::controllers::CommandController>("CMS", 1, 0, "CommandController");
```

I created 2 component Qml files and successfully (atleast i think so) exported them in my components module:

```
//CommandBar.qml
import QtQuick 2.12
import assets 1.0

Item {
    property alias commandList: commandRepeater.model

    anchors {
        left: parent.left
        bottom: parent.bottom
        right: parent.right
    }

    height: Style.heightCommandBar

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: Style.colorCommandBarBackground

        Row {
            anchors {
                top: parent.top
                bottom: parent.bottom
                right: parent.right
            }

            Repeater {
                id: commandRepeater
                delegate: CommandButton {
                    command: modelData
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


//CommandButton.qml

import QtQuick 2.12
import CMS 1.0
import assets 1.0

Item {
    property Command command
    width: Style.widthCommandButton
    height: Style.heightCommandButton

    Rectangle {
        id: background
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: Style.colorCommandBarBackground

        //Command button icon
        Text {
            id: textIcon

            anchors {
                centerIn: parent
                verticalCenterOffset: -10
            }
            font {
                family: Style.fontAwesomeSolid
                pixelSize: Style.pixelSizeCommandBarIcon
            }

            color: command.ui_canExecute ? Style.colorCommandBarFont : Style.colorCommandBarFontDisabled

            text: command.ui_iconCharacter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }

        //Command button description
        Text {
            id: textDescription

            anchors {
                top: textIcon.bottom
                bottom: parent.bottom
                left: parent.left
                right: parent.right
            }

            font.pixelSize: Style.pixelSizeNavigationBarText

            color: command.ui_canExecute ? Style.colorCommandBarFont : Style.colorCommandBarFontDisabled
            text: command.ui_description
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
            hoverEnabled: true
            onEntered: background.state = "hover"
            onExited: background.state = ""
            onClicked: if(command.ui_canExecute) {
                           command.executed();
                       }
        }

        states: [
            State {
                name: "hover"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: background
                    color: Qt.darker(Style.colorCommandBarBackground)
                }
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

I used created components inside CreatePatientView.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import assets 1.0
import components 1.0

Item {

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: Style.colorBackground
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Create patient view"
        }
    }

    CommandBar {
        commandList: masterController.ui_commandController.ui_createClientViewContextCommands
    }

}
```

And used the view inside MasterView.qml

For the beginning, im trying to display single "save" button (icon + description) onto my CreatePatientView, before I implement more buttons.

Sadly, the icon + description command button is not displayed, mouse hover area isn't present neither. Im new to Qml and UI, so I cannot figure out what might be the problem.

Sorry for lots of code, but I simply do not know where should I look for source of problem.

Best regards.

EDIT:

After doing some digging, I have found the following:

- if the CommandButton is declared explicitly outside of CommandBar, and initialized using aliases, the button is populated and displayed correctly - therefore, I think that my problem is connected to populating CommandButton's using Repeater OR displaying it within row in CommandBar.qml
- I have placed simple onCompleted console logs inside CommandBar and CommandButton root Item's - if i DO NOT use any explicit CommandButtons but those populated with metaData, the CommandBar qml is being read, while CommandButton is not.

Can somebody point out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: the root item has no size i.e. the size is (0,0) so that's the reason you can't see it. If you want some "autogrow" container I would recommend [RowLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-rowlayout.html) or similar.

Comment: Which root item are u talking about exactly?

Comment: The last part of code, the root Item has no size. Actually, this is the most difficult way to create a button I've ever seen. Also it looks that you've forgot to provide `CommandButton` source. Where is the visual representation of your button?

Comment: I have moved entirety of button implementation and handling to C++. For now, u can see it hard coded inside first part of code: "save" description + text representing it in FontAwesome ( inside Implementation constructor for CommandController). Command button source is in the last part of code - it contains 2 Qml files

Comment: If i include CommandButton component inside other, ex. NavigationBar component, and initialize it explicitly using aliases, the component data is filled correctly. Therefore, problem is connected to populating it using Repeater or displaying of CommandButton ( i suppose)